# Convert ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application to Windows 10 Universal Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have an web application developed over ASP.NET MVC 5 Framework. Now, i want to convert this web application to Native Windows Phone application for publishing it to Windows Store not to re-developed for Windows Phone.

Is there any method for this conversion?,

Comment: Adding a new UI to the project and reuse the rest of the Logic/Data projects from the MVC app?

Comment: I am asking is there any method that i can convert it easily using tool, method or etc. Your reply is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, i want to convert this web application to Native Windows Phone application for publishing it to Windows Store not to re-developed for Windows Phone.

It is possible, but you still need some extra effort to re-structure your application framework.

**ASP.NET MVC = Model + View + Controller**

**Native Store App = Frontend (View + ViewModel) + Backend (REST Service)**

In the frontend, considering using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript so that you can reuse some code in your ASP.NET MVC project.

In the backend, converting the ASP.NET MVC Controller to ASP.NET WEB API.

This blog may give you some help.

[Migrate ASP.NET MVC application to Windows Store apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/11/12/migrate-asp-net-mvc-application-to-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No. There's not. Such a tool would an impossibility as a web application != native mobile application. You *could* use something like Cordova, which might at least let you reuse some of your HTML, but you'd still need to build a separate UI targeting that.

Comment: There is such a link but i do not understand these steps can be applied for ASP.NET MVC 5 or not [link](http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm)

Comment: That's not really *converting* the web application into a universal app. It's more akin to a WebView layer, that can "call out" to native APIs. You still must have a web application hosted somewhere, and the application can only work if there's an internet connection to get to it. So, *not* a native app. Microsoft did this in an attempt to get more apps on it's platform by packaging up websites as "apps", at least until they started getting in hot water from a ton of those websites complaining about these unofficial "official" apps.